# change value of checkbox onclick event using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

```
<input type="checkbox" id="read" name="permission" onclick="$(this).val(this.checked ? 1 : 0)"/>   
<input type="checkbox" id="read" name="permission" onclick="$(this).val(this.checked ? 1 : 0)"/>   
<input type="checkbox" id="read" name="permission" onclick="$(this).val(this.checked ? 1 : 0)"/>   
<input type="checkbox" id="read" name="permission" onclick="$(this).val(this.checked ? 1 : 0)"/>   
<input type="checkbox" id="read" name="permission" onclick="$(this).val(this.checked ? 1 : 0)"/>
```

i want to change the value of check box 
  suppose

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="0">Check
```

after `onclick` event it will change like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="1">Check
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It makes no sense. If the checkbox is not checked then no value is sent to the server, so leave them all as `1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use on `change` function of checkbox and change value. If checked like

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("change",function(){
   if($(this).is(":checked"))
      $(this).val("1");
    else
      $(this).val("0");
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu7535mx/)**